# Mui Autocomplete renderGroup props: access options object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to access the `options` object passed in `Autocomplete` inside `renderGroup` just like you can in `renderOption`?

Mui gives this signature for `renderGroup`:

```
function(params: AutocompleteRenderGroupParams) => ReactNode
```

where `AutocompleteRenderGroupParams` is:

```
export interface AutocompleteRenderGroupParams {
  key: string;
  group: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend autocomplete option or skip straight

https://mui.com/joy-ui/api/autocomplete-option/

Comment: My question is about mui Autocomplete, not joy-ui